# Passing on validated variables to a different page (PHP)

Tags: php

On form index.php I have three input fields (Name, Surname and Date of Birth) which I want to pass along to form myProfile.php, the user cannot continue to the next myProfile.php unless all three fields have been completed. 
How can I send the variables to the next page, once it has been determined that all the input fields are valid?  Currently I can determine that all the input fields are valid, but I don't know how to pass the variables along to myProfile.php

Variables and Input handling (index.php):

```
<?php

$nameErr = $surnameErr = $dobErr =  "";
$name = $surname = $dob = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
    $surnameErr = "Surname is required";
  } else {
    $surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["dob"])) {
    $dobErr = "Date of Birth is required";
  } else {
    $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Creating the form (index.php):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Surname:
<input type="text" name="surname">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $surnameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Date of Birth:
<input type="date" name="dob">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $dobErr;?></span>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

My problem is that in order to send my name, surname and date of birth to myProfile.php, I need the form action to be `action="myProfile.php"`, however for the input validation to take place it has to be `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>`".  How can I allow the input validation to take place, and if all the input is valid, then pass the variables along to myProfile.php in order to use the following code:

myProfile.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo "My name is " . $name . " " . $surname . ". I am " . date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('today'))->y . " years old.";
?>
```

Comment: You can store them in a session

Comment: Change this into a client side validation and you are done

Comment: @LelioFaieta client-side valdation can be skipped by hackers or other sneaky folks.

Comment: @S.Imp yes. I expect the server side to be done on the target page. Just to prevent what you correctly say

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [PHP's session functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to do this. Sessions are not specific to PHP, but PHP has functions which make it easy to maintain data about a specific visitor. This can be tricky because HTTP is a *stateless protocol*.

In index.php, *after you have made sure that the data is valid* you can store it in session by calling session_start and using the superglobal $_SESSION variable:

```
if ($data_is_valid) // you'll have to figure out yourself whether data is valid or not
{
    session_start(); // you must call this before using $_SESSION
    $_SESSION["valid_data"] = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "surname" => $surname,
        "dob" => $dob
    );

    // redirect the user to the other page
    header("location: myProfile.php");
    // always remember to exit after redirecting or code may continue to execute
    exit;
}
```

Then, in my Profile.php, you can call session_start and check for the valid data

```
session_start();
if (!array_key_exists("valid_data", $_SESSION)) {
    die("No valid data found!"); // you might want to redirect back to the first page or something?
}
$data = $_SESSION["valid_data"];
if (!is_array($data)) {
    die("Data found is not an array!");
}


// otherwise, data was found...you can keep going!
// you might get errors here if you didn't set these properly on the the previous page
$name = $data['name'];
$surname = $data['surname'];
$dob = $data['dob'];
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "My name is " . $name . " " . $surname . ". I am " . date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('today'))->y . " years old.";
```

Comment: I have tried incorporating your code into mine, but I have gone terribly wrong.  I am still quite new to PHP.  Could you kindly show me where you would insert the code you have given me into my original code?